# Current/Active Navigation Link State in Magento

Tags: css, magento, navigation

I built custom navigation for my Magento site, now I'm scrambling on how to add:

```
class="current"
```

to the list item the user is currently viewing.
Thanks,
-Sam

Comment: which part are you stuck on? Getting the current page, where to add the code, other? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm not sure where/how to add code with the argument "if this is current url add class active"

Comment: You imply this is a custom navigation system, so I have no idea where you would add it since you built it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear what you are looking for - but if you mean that you have added CMS pages to the standard menu (which is a common requirement) then you can test what cms page you are on using

```
Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();
```

The menu is usually called in `catalog/navigation/top.phtml` and this is not a bad place to add extra static links.

If that is not what you mean, could you give more details? Including what you have tried/what custom code you are using.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  My navigation is a static, unordered list within header.phtml. So I believe I would need to add php to header.phtml in order to provide a "current" class. I just don't know what PHP to add.

Comment: This method doesn't work when cache is on. You will always get identifier of the cached page.